# Как создать файл заданного размера со случайным содержимым используя sh linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Необходимо с помощью sh linux создавать файлы заданного размера и случайным содержимым.

Comment: Первая же выдача в гугл по запросу "bash create random file" [How can I populate a file with random data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33629/how-can-i-populate-a-file-with-random-data)

Answer (score 2):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=myfile bs=1K count=1
```

Можно с помощью dd, смотря для чего.

Comment: Файлы необходимы для исследования предельных возможностей архиватора на определённой платформе